# Determining the size of grid cells in a raster

Tags: r, raster

Is there a good method for determining the size of individual grid cells in a `RasterLayer`? I can access the resolution but I need the actual size in km^2.  I've tried using the `area()` with my raster but it's not finding the window. I've also tried creating a `SpatialGridDataFrame` from my raster but have had no luck computing the area of each individual grid cell. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The cells size is the product of the x and y resolution `prod(res(x))` if you have a planar coordinate reference system. Otherwise, if your crs is longitude/latitude, cell size will change with latitude, and you can indeed use the `area` function to get the size of each cell.

I take it that "it's not finding the window." refers to this error message `Error in as.owin.default(w) : Can't interpret W as a window`.

This is a name conflict with `spatstat`. So either do not load `spatstat` or call the raster function explicitly `raster::area(x)`.